# What types of multiplayer modes are there?

Tags: halo-wars-2

I am curious about the multiplayer game modes in Halo Wars 2.

During the Beta, there was only one mode available and that was Blitz. I didn't really enjoy this new spin on an RTS game, and now I am wondering what game modes are available before I purchase it.

If there are no multiplayer modes that I might like, I would only buy it for the story line and to have it in my Halo collection, but then I'd rather wait until the price drops a little bit in a few weeks or months.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the game modes include:

- Domination: *Capture and hold Control Towers to Score Points.*
- Strongholds: *Build and hold the most Strongholds at the end of the match to win.*
- Deathmatch: *Destroy all enemy bases to win.*
- Blitz
- Campaign (coop and single player)

You can also team up and play against the AI in matchmaking in Domination, Strongholds, and Deathmatch (3 vs. 3 style) as well as in the above game modes against other players.

Source: I have the game already.

<sub>Italicized text is part of the in game descriptions for each mode</sub>